# way to package python lambda python files with no requirements.txt

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, package

Is there a way to package lambda files that do not have requirements.txt? For using docker or other methods we need to have requirements.txt. Please share ur opinions !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at a minimum you just need to zip the code.  If the handler function is in a file named my_lambda.py, then your zip needs to have this file at the root.  If your code has 3rd-party dependencies, you must add them to the zip yourself--they won't get automatically installed by Lambda.

Check out

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/build-python-lambda-deployment-package/

Also, you may want to consider using Lambda Layers: https://medium.com/@adhorn/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-layers-for-python-6e10b1f9a5d